# Changing desktop in OS X Lion with Python AppScript library

Tags: python, osx-lion, py-appscript

My goal is to change every Mac OS X Lion background (on each Mission Control spaces and on each screen) using the py-appscript.

I've found a piece of code on SO that changes the background :

```
from appscript import app, mactypes
finder = app('Finder')
finder.desktop_picture.set(mactypes.File('/Path/To/Pictures/mypic.png'))
```

I would like a code that enables me to set the background for a given space, or that let me change current space in order to set the background to manually each space.

An opportunity to set the background for a given external screen would be a plus (my sample code just change the background for the main monitor).